# I would like to change the background of my Shopify site when i click a button

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I would like to be able to click the colored buttons I have and make it change the background color of my whole site. Here is an example of a site that has this feature: https://seasonofsunday.com/

Here is the liquid I have so far

```
<style>
  .butt {
    border: 1px outset black;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.butt:hover {
   border: 2px outset black;
}

</style>

{%- for block in section.blocks -%}
  {%- case block.type -%}
    {%- when 'announcement' -%}
      <div class="announcement-bar" role="region" aria-label="{{ 'sections.header.announcement' | t }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
        {%- if block.settings.text != blank -%}
          {%- if block.settings.link != blank -%}
            <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}" class="announcement-bar__link link link--text focus-inset animate-arrow">
          {%- endif -%}
              <div class="page-width">
                <p class="announcement-bar__message {{ block.settings.text_alignment }} h5">
                  {{ block.settings.text | escape }}
          
          {% if block.settings.colors_background_1 != blank %}
                  <button onclick="myFunction()"  class="butt" type="button" style="background-color: {{block.settings.colors_background_1}};"></button>
                  {% else %}
                  {% endif %}
          {% if block.settings.colors_background_2 != blank %}
                  <input class="butt" type="button" style="background-color: {{block.settings.colors_background_2}};"/>
                  {% else %}
                  {% endif %}
          {% if block.settings.colors_background_3 != blank %}
                  <input class="butt" type="button" style="background-color: {{block.settings.colors_background_3}};"/>
                  {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if block.settings.colors_background_4 != blank %}
                  <input  class="butt" type="button" style="background-color: {{block.settings.colors_background_4}};"/>
                  {% else %}
                  
                  {% endif %}
          
                  {%- if block.settings.link != blank -%}
                    {% render 'icon-arrow' %}
                  {%- endif -%}
                </p>
              </div>
          {%- if block.settings.link != blank -%}
            </a>
          {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
      </div>
  {%- endcase -%}
{%- endfor -%}


{% schema %}
{
  "name": "test",
  "max_blocks": 12,
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "announcement",
      "name": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.name",
      "settings": [
       {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "text",
          "default": "Welcome to our store",
          "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.settings.text.label"
        },
        {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "colors_background_1",
        "label": "Color"
      },
                {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "colors_background_2",
        "label": "Color"
      },
                {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "colors_background_3",
        "label": "Color"
      },
                {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "colors_background_4",
        "label": "Color"
      },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "text_alignment",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "left",
              "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.settings.text_alignment.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "center",
              "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.settings.text_alignment.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "right",
              "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.settings.text_alignment.options__3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "center",
          "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.settings.text_alignment.label"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "default": {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "announcement"
      }
    ]
  }
}
{% endschema %}
```

I know there has to be some JavaScript but idk what I'm doing.
Let me know if you have questions.